# iOS iFrame containing responsive page

Tags: ios, css, iframe, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I'm trying to embed our page on a clients site, it works great in a browser and our media queries do a great job, but when inside an ifarme on an idevice, the embedded page doesn't act responsively and displays in the biggest media query size (>870px wide) and it looks really small...

Any idea why this ahppens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We learned it the hard way.

inside iFrame,

- the media query is not aware of the parent window screen size
- in some browsers, the iFrame actual height/width will be more than the CSS width/height shown in the parent page

In short, media query is not fully compatible with iFrames.

We resorted to implementing our own media query like behaviour through javascript.

In summary it is like below,

- the parent page loads iFrame [in a popup in our case, after user clicks a link]
- the iFrame sets up onmessage event listener
- the parent page initiates postMessage to iFrame
- the iFrame receives parent window width, height from parent page and any other necessary info
- the iFrame manually re-adjusts the layout through javascript

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play with that, we have javascript to post window height to the parent window, to resize the iframe to fit the content, so maybe we can do something similar to make it respond properly :/